# How to create an array if an array does not exist yet?

Tags: javascript

How do I create an array if it does not exist yet? In other words how to default a variable to an empty array?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

If you want to check whether an array x exists and create it if it doesn't, you can do

```
x = ( typeof x != 'undefined' && x instanceof Array ) ? x : []
```

Comment: This works in most cases, but it won't cover you if you plan on checking an array instantiated from a different global `Array` constructor - this might occur when scripting across frames.

Comment: That is true. How would one handle that case?

Comment: @Rich: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961528/javascript-check-if-array-exist-if-not-create-it/1961653#1961653, it will behave correctly on multi-framed DOM environments.

Comment: The correct way to do it nowadays is to use `Array.isArray(x)`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38670091/271442

Comment: It doesn't work when it is **null**. So a complete check would be `if (Array.isArray(array) && array.length)` You can find more here https://stackoverflow.com/a/24403771/364951

Comment: That is not correct. `Array.isArray(null)` will be `false`. Your check is verifying it's a non-empty array.

Answer (score 70):

```
var arr = arr || [];
```

Comment: But this doesn’t check if *arr* is an array.

Comment: You're right. It wasn't clear from the question if checking that it was an array in advance is necessary, or just checking to see if the variable is already defined. This is a common idiom, and is shorter and simpler than the other ones posted, so I figured I'd post it and let the questioner decide if it's sufficient.

Comment: If `arr` is already defined in the relevant scope, then why bother with `var ...`? You can just do `arr = arr || [];`

Comment: The question was to check whether the array already exists, and create it if not. Thus, you don't know if it's already defined. This idiom is useful if you have several files to be linked together, and don't know which one of them will be loaded first to define some global variable that they will all share.

Comment: @BrianCampbell I might be wrong but unless that's being run in global scope, wouldn't `var` be hoisted and therefore it'd always just become `[]`? Edit: nvm, I am wrong :D

Answer (score 66):

```
const list = Array.isArray(x) ? x : [x];
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray

Or if `x` *could* be an array and you want to make sure it is one:

```
const list = [].concat(x);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Comment: Throws `x is not defined` in both cases

Comment: `x` is the variable that could be an array or not. You define that. This is just example code ...

Answer (score 13):

You can use the [`typeof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/typeof_Operator) to test for *undefined* and the [`instanceof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/instanceof_Operator) to test if it’s an instance of *Array*:

```
if (typeof arr == "undefined" || !(arr instanceof Array)) {
    var arr = [];
}
```

Comment: You can skip the first check, because `undefined` isn't an instanceof Array.

Comment: @zackehh If you do so, it can throw an error if `arr` is not yet defined

Answer (score 9):

If you want to check if the object is already an Array, to avoid the [well known issues](http://ajaxian.com/archives/isarray-why-is-it-so-bloody-hard-to-get-right) of the `instanceof` operator when working in multi-framed DOM environments, you could use the `Object.prototype.toString` method:

```
arr = Object.prototype.toString.call(arr) == "[object Array]" ? arr : [];
```

Comment: @kangax Declaration isn't necessary in this context.

Comment: The declaration is necessary, but I thought it was pretty obvious that if `arr` is undeclared a `ReferenceError` will be thrown in the right-hand side of the assignment...

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

array1  = new Array('apple','mango','banana');
var storearray1 =array1;

if (window[storearray1] && window[storearray1] instanceof Array) {
    alert("exist!");
} else {
    alert('not find: storearray1 = ' + typeof storearray1)
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score -7):

If you are talking about a browser environment then all global variables are members of the window object. So to check:

```
if (window.somearray !== undefined) {
    somearray = [];
}
```