# how to check if a collection has value in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I wanted to check whether a collection has value or not, I did like below and its working. Please suggest if we have any better approach...

I am checking if `data` is `[]` then do nothing, else do something

```
let data = await this.http.post(_postsURL, {
  headers: this.getPostAPIHeader()
}).toPromise();
if (data[0]) {
  console.log("response yes ");
} else {
  console.log("response no ");
}
```

Comment: The better approach would be to check data.length. data[0] might contain a falsy value and break your check

Comment: Determinate if `0 === data.length`.

Comment: `if (!data || !data.length) { console.log('empty'); } else { console.log('has values'); }`

Comment: Your text says you compare `data` to `[]`, but your code checks `data[0]` for truthiness. If you want to compare `data` to `[]` then use `if (data == [])`, although as others have noted, it's better to check the length. See [Check if array is empty / does not exist. JS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24403732)

Answer (score 0):

try this instead:

```
if (data.length===0 || !date) {
  console.log("response yes ");
} else {
  console.log("response no ");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if (data !==undefined && data.length >0) {
  console.log("response yes ");
} else {
  console.log("response no ");
}
```