# Checking existence of object key inside filter method?

Tags: javascript

Inside a filter I need to test for a variety of conditions.

```
filter(books, (book) => {

    return myFilters.authors.map(a => a.id).includes(book.author_id) &&
    myFilters.skus.map(a => a.id).includes(book.sku);
    ....
```

There are other conditions depending on the type of filter, e.g. `myFilters.price` will be a different test.

I'm just wondering if you could point me in the right direction in terms of testing inside the filter, as if `myFilter` does not have any authors the `map` method will fail. How can I test for `authors` existing on `myFilters` (using something like `authors in myFilters`) but inside the `filter` method?

Something like:

```
filter(books, (book) => {

    return DOES AUTHORS EXIST ON MY FILTERS? myFilters.authors.map(a => a.id).includes(book.author_id) &&
    DO SKUS EXIST ON MY FILTERS? myFilters.skus.map(a => a.id).includes(book.sku);
    ....
```

Comment: on a side note you should not call your function filter, as it's already a native method in javascript. Now for your problem, you could chain methods, as in `myFilters.filter(filter => filter.hasOwnProperty('author')).map(etc..)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if array is empty or does not exist. JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24403732/check-if-array-is-empty-or-does-not-exist-js)

Comment: @BernardPagoaga that would not work as when a property does not exist, it will return false inside the entire filter, I want it to ignore it and not return false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the logical `||` OR operator to substitute an empty array when one does not exist.

```
return (myFilters.authors || []).map(...)
```

But I think it's better if you're able to control the structure to make it such that there will always be an array, even if empty.

---

If you need to exclude that part of the filter when the array doesn't exist, then use the conditional operator.

```
return (myFilters.author ? myFilters.authors.map(...).includes(...) : true) &&
       (myFilters.skus ? myFilters.skus.map(...).includes(...) : true)
```

---

However, it really seems like a separate function would be of benefit here. Something like this:

```
function includesIfExists(arr, prop, val) {
  return arr ? arr.map(v => v[prop]).includes(val) : true
}
```

Then:

```
return includesIfExists(myFilters.authors, "id", book.id) && ...
```

---

And actually, the function could use `.some()` so that you're not iterating twice.

```
function includesIfExists(arr, prop, val) {
  return arr ? arr.some(v => v[prop] === val) : true
}
```

Comment: But with an empty array there will be no matches, if nothing exists I want to skip that part of the filter, not run it and return nothing.

Comment: Oh, I see. You could instead use the conditional operator `? :` to test each one first. I'll update.

Comment: Or just use an `if`/`else` if like me you have a pathological hatred of tenary if statements

Comment: Interesting - returning true if the item does not exist, clever idea, thanks.

Comment: @Liam cant use if/else in return.

Comment: @Liam: I think he meant `if/else` as an expression like you can in some languages.

Comment: @ziggywiggy great stuff!

Answer (score 0):

```
filter(books, (book) => {
    return myFilters.authors.map(a => a.id).includes(book.author_id) &&  
    myFilters.skus.map(a => a.id).includes(book.sku);  
    ....
```

You could easily check for the truthiness and perform your expression if it exists.  This is known as a [Guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guard_(computer_science)).  If it doesn't evaluate to true, using the OR operator will default it to `true` so your *return* expression can proceed. It's very similar to a ternary operator.

Consider:

```
filter(books, (book) => {
  return 
    ( myFilters.authors && myFilters.authors.map(a => a.id).includes(book.author_id) || true ) &&
    ( myFilters.skus && myFilters.skus.map(a => a.id).includes(book.sku) || true );
    ...
```

---

#### Readability

There are several reasons why you may not want to do this.  The main reason may be for readability and maintainability.  Your code is short and concise; however, 5 years from now (or even in 2 months) will you be able to quickly know how to modify it or fix a bug?  Will someone else?

For that, it's generally better to be more expressive:

```
filter(books, (book) => {
   let has_authors     = true       // default case if author filters not supplied
   let has_skus        = true       // default case if skus filters not supplied
   let {authors, skus} = myFilters  // destructuring assignment for code legibility

   if ( authors )
     has_authors = authors.map(a => a.id).includes(book.author_id)

   if ( skus )
     has_skus = skus.map(a => a.id).includes(book.sku)

  return has_authors && has_skus
}
```

Of course, this could be further improved using `some` to minimize the number of iterations (one loop instead of two) and a function call to reduce the syntax, making it DRYer:

```
filter(books, (book) => {
   let has_authors     = true       // default case if author filters not supplied
   let has_skus        = true       // default case if skus filters not supplied
   let {authors, skus} = myFilters  // destructuring assignment for code legibility

   if ( authors )
     has_authors = hasId( authors, book.author_id )

   if ( skus )
     has_skus = hasId( skus, book.sku )

  return has_authors && has_skus
}

function hasId( array, id ) {
  return array.some(v => v.id == id )
}
```

#### Working Example of the Above

```js
setup() // create globals and functions


let filtered_books = filter(books, (book) => {
   let has_authors     = true       // default case if author filters not supplied
   let has_skus        = true       // default case if skus filters not supplied
   let {authors, skus} = myFilters  // destructuring assignment for code legibility

   if ( authors )
     has_authors = hasId( authors, book.author_id )

   if ( skus )
     has_skus = hasId( skus, book.sku )

  return has_authors && has_skus
})

function hasId( array, id ) {
  return array.some(v => v.id == id )
}

console.log(`filtered_books: `, filtered_books)
console.log(`from: `, books)





function setup(){

  window.myFilters = {
    // authors: [ { id: 7 } ],  // <-- uncomment to show a case where no authors match
    skus: [
      { id: 3 },
      { id: 5 }
    ]
  }
  window.books = [
    {author_id:4, sku: 2},
    {author_id:5, sku: 3}
  ]
  window.filter = function(array, callback){
    return array.filter(callback)
  }
}
```