# How to check if array is empty?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this codes below and how can I check if the `ar` is empty?

```
  let ar2 = [];
  const items = users[0]?.[2]?.itemList;
  if (items) {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(items)) {
      ar2.push(key, <br />);
    }
  }
```

if I'll `console.log(ar2)`, it shows this [ ]

How can I check it the array is empty and then display the message "This is empty"?

I tried this but it's not working correctly. Even if it's greater than or less than 0, it will always display "2"

```
 {ar2 < 0 ? <>1</> : <>2</>}
```

Comment: you can use `ar.length === 0` to check it. If `ar.length === 0` is `true` then it is empty else it has some content in it. Refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if array is empty or does not exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24403732/how-to-check-if-array-is-empty-or-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ar2.length will show you the number of elements in the array.

You could simply do this:

```
{ar2.length === 0 && 'This is empty'}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can first check if it is an array and then you can check for the emptiness using `length` property

**1)** You can first check whether the `ar2` is an array or not using static [`isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) function. Because you can create an object which has `length` property but it may or may not be an `array`

```js
function isEmptyNotRecommended(obj) {
  return obj.length === 0;
}

function isEmptyRecommended(obj) {
  return Array.isArray(obj) && obj.length === 0;
}

const arr = { length: 0 };
// This is not an array but still returns true
console.log(isEmptyNotRecommended(arr));  

// This should be recommended approach to check for array emptiness
console.log(isEmptyRecommended(arr));
```

**`RECOMMENDED SOLUTION ⬇`**

**2)** If it is an array then It is safe to use `length` property on it. If its length is `more than 0` then it is `not empty` else it is `empty`

You can either use `ar2.length === 0` or `!ar2.length`

```
{
  Array.isArray(ar2) && !ar2.length ? <>1</> : <>2</>;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `length` property will return the number of items in the array.

If you want to check whether an array is empty, check whether it's `length` property is `0`.

```js
{ar2.length == 0 ? <>1</> : <>2</>}
```

Comment: Use `===` instead of `==`

Answer (score 0):

You should follow this step:

- if `ar` is undefined?
- if `ar` is array
- if `ar` is empty

all of that, you would have this condition:

```
ar2 !== undefined && Array.isArray(ar2) && ar2.length > 0
```

Comment: No need to use `ar2 !== undefined`, This check is redundant because `Array.isArray(ar2)` will return `false` if it is not an array.

Comment: @decpk thankyou for the correction.