Find first non empty array in object array
So I keep running into this issue trying to use javascripts array.find method. I have a JSON object where im extracting an array of objects that looks like this:
[
  {
    Id: 5303,
    Widgets: [],
  },
  {
    Id: 5302,
    Widgets: [
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object]
    ],
  }
]

In my case I need to grab the first object where the Widgets array is NOT empty.
So I assumed i'd do something like this:
SomeArray.find((foo) => (foo.Widgets!= undefined))
Since checking length does not work as it'll give undefined on an empty length array. So I tried adding an || option checking the length (Well that doesn't work either since it gives null reading of length on empty array)
So how exactly can I return the first object where the widgets array is not empty? It seems to work about half the time because occasionally it'll return the object where the widgets array is in fact empty.

An empty array is not the same as being undefined; try checking for the array length.

@mykaf That doesn't work sadly as you'll get an undefined error on the first empty array it comes across.

An empty array has length of 0; please show how you implemented that and we can adjust your code. I was able to make a simple change to your attempt to get a working example.

@mykaf I think I see the issue, for some reason my console was showing the array as [] (empty) but it was indeed null in the actual response value so that's why it wasn't working. Changing it to != null appeared to work.

Be aware that the console evaluates deeper content asynchronously, so that -- when you expand a view on an object in the console -- you get to see the more current contents of that object, not the state at the moment console.log was executed.

A way to catch both scenarios (empty array and null), you could use foo => foo.widgets?.length as callback for find.

Looks like you want: (foo.Widgets != undefined && foo.Widgets.length > 0)  (other code variants are available)

So it looks like something odd is happening. SOMETIMES it's showing null for the value and sometimes it's showing [] which is why it's failing occasionally. Is there a way to check for both cases? I have no idea why it would do this. (Im using Playwright's API testing)

Both of the comments just above your last one show ways to check for both cases.

See existing, detailed, answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24403732/how-to-check-if-array-is-empty-or-does-not-exist/24403771#24403771

To catch both scenarios, where you want to discard objects that have either null or an empty array as value for widgets, you can use this callback for your find method:
foo => foo.widgets?.length

You wrote:

checking length does not work as it'll give undefined on an empty length array.

That is a misunderstanding. An empty array has a length property that is 0. Be aware that console.log of an object will build a representation of that object asynchronously. If that object is mutated after that console.log executed and before you expand the view of that object in the console, you'll see the mutated state. See console.log() shows the changed value of a variable before the value actually changes.

Thanks, I was not super familiar with the optional chaining operator so this seems to be working. However the object isn't getting mutated so im still not super sure why sometimes it's being null vs []
