# Pushing Multiple dataLayer's

Tags: google-tag-manager

I want to push a dataLayer on an eccommerce site for Dynamic remarketing. My code sits under some previous dataLayer pushed they had in place:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "https://www.ecample.com/gauncached/index/gaIsLoggedIn/"
}).done(function(response) {
    dataLayer.push({
        'Logged In': response
    });
});
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "https://www.example.com/gauncached/index/hasCustomerPurchased/"
}).done(function(response) {
    dataLayer.push({
        'Is Purchaser': response
    });
});
```

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    dataLayer.push({
        'ecomm_prodid': ['04-04-542-399-02-02-50'],
        'ecomm_pagetype' : 'cart',
        'ecomm_totalvalue' : 615.00        });
</script>
```

This is not being recognised in my debug. Is it because I have multiple dataLayer's?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is probably not being recognized because of JS error. You cannot have HTML tag within JS code block, so just remove like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "https://www.ecample.com/gauncached/index/gaIsLoggedIn/"
}).done(function(response) {
    dataLayer.push({
        'Logged In': response
    });
});
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "https://www.example.com/gauncached/index/hasCustomerPurchased/"
}).done(function(response) {
    dataLayer.push({
        'Is Purchaser': response
    });
});

//note that there is no need to initialize dataLayer again    
dataLayer.push({
    'ecomm_prodid': ['04-04-542-399-02-02-50'],
    'ecomm_pagetype' : 'cart',
    'ecomm_totalvalue' : 615.00        
});
</script>
```

"This is not being recognised in my debug. Is it because I have multiple dataLayer's?" - you don't have multiple dataLayer's in the first place. With your code:

```
var dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
```

You are checking if the dataLayer is already declared, which it is so you are referencing the same dataLayer. You can have a look at simliar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1961539/7064943 ... I hope this helps