# Append data to an array otherwise create one in ES6

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
  if (typeof my.nested.dataset !== "undefined") {
    my.nested.dataset.push(data);
  } else {
    my.nested.dataset = [data];
  }
```

I need to push data to an array but only if the array exists otherwise I need to create one.

I'm repeating `my.nested.dataset` three times. What alternatives do I have to append/assign at once.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript: check if array exist, if not create it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961528/javascript-check-if-array-exist-if-not-create-it)

Comment: The answer below is more concise although the more important question is do you call that code in more than one place.  If so, you should really put the code into a function say function addToNestedDataset(data). Then it doesn't really matter that your code is a bit more verbose as it is easier for the next perhaps less experience developer to read and understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can initialize your `dataset` via `my.nested.dataset = my.nested.dataset || []`.

And then in the code you don't need to check with `if`. Just call *push* on it

```
 my.nested.dataset.push(data);
```

In one line

```
(my.nested.dataset = my.nested.dataset || []).push(data)
```

Comment: Can I do it in one line like you did before the edit (`(my.nested.dataset || []).push(data)`)?

Comment: In that case you need to put appropriate `()`. I have edited

Comment: Should we not close as dupe?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a one-liner, it's

```
(my.nested.dataset = my.nested.dataset || []).push(data);
```

but that still repeats `my.nested`. If it's a really long name, make a helper variable for it. You cannot avoid repeating `.data`.

Comment: Should we not close as dupe?

Comment: I have already marked it as dupe. Hope it justifies the question's scope